# Using both wired and wireless ubuntu 12.10 no bonding

Tags: 12.10, wireless, networking, internet, network-manager

i've got an PC running ubuntu 12.10. i have 2 connection: a wired connect to the internet through router A,  and the wireless connection to the internet through router B. Now i have try to search the internet how to combine these two connections.
first of all i have read about bonding solution, i've tried it, but a problem happened: i cannot control my two cards in the Network Manager, so i cannot select which wireless network to connect to. The BONDING is not a good solution.
Now i try to look for an easy solution with GUI config but i found nothing appropriate to my need.
Thanks for all coming help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy, GUI solution.
Too hard solution: Joining 2 network, [MultiISP](http://www.shorewall.net/MultiISP.html)